# Gcc.exe Runtime error

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, gcc

I recently just installed `MinGW` in Windows. However, when I try to compile a simple `hello.c` program I get this error message

```
C:\Users\HP-PC\Desktop\eclipse-workspace\FirstProject>gcc hello.c

Cannot create temporary file in C:\Users\HP-PC\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\MinGW\bin\:
Invalid argument
```

This application has requested the `Runtime` to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

I have tried reinstalling MinGW, but the error persists. I have also tried checking gcc --version and g++ -- version, and these worked without problems.

Comment: Using the `set` command, check the values of `TEMP` and `TMP`.

Comment: sounds like a file permissions thing. Have you tried compiling from an Administrative command prompt (although I would hope you wouldn't _have_ to do this)

Comment: Along with Harrys suggestion, check whether the weird path "C:\Users\HP-PC\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\MinGW\bin\:" is in your environment variable `TEMP` or in `TMP`. It seems that one of them contains the whole thing (which looks like two paths instead of one; the second broken, `:` in unexpected position and also unplausible) and the tool tries to write a temporary file there. So type `set TEMP` and `set TMP` to see whether Harry is on the right track.

Comment: @Yunnosch, the colon at the end is probably just part of the error message, that's a fairly common syntax.  Benedict, my second wild guess is that perhaps MinGW doesn't like there being a hyphen in your username.  You could try creating a temporary folder `C:\TEMP`, making sure you have access to write to it, and pointing TEMP and TMP at that.

Comment: Thanks! I must have overlooked that. It works well now.